# Offline backups for OneNote

Tags: backup, privacy, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-surface-pro

I'm using Microsoft's OneNote on my Surface, is it possible to make offline backups of my notes? (Export my notes to a file)

I am using OneNote version 16.0.3327.1043, it doesn't say anything about a year.

All of the information I've found online for saving copies of your notes only applies to OneNote 2003, 2007, and 2010.

For privacy reasons, I don't sync my notes to Microsoft's cloud and I want to make backups for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there are actually two versions of OneNote. The OneNote Metro app which comes preinstalled with the Surface is different than the OneNote desktop version.

If you go to [onenote.com](https://onenote.com) and install the "Office" version, you can make offline backups of your notes.